# Getting multiple rows of inputs without specifying the number of rows 'n'

Tags: python

How can I get multiple lines of input in python 3 without specifying the number of lines? Someone please help me out...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
contents = []
while True:
    try:
        line = input()
    except EOFError:
        break
    contents.append(line)
```

Comment: @SundaraAadithyan no problem, glad to help you. Remember to finish up the question-answer procedure.